# How to publish *all* elements of a Flux source, to an unknown count of consumers

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

When servicing a request asynchronously, multiple steps need to take place. The output of a specific publisher is required to be consumed by multiple sub flows, without skipping elements, e.g. as a result of subscribing late/mid flight.

It is not desired to re-execute the request which generates the source flux (read rows from the DB only once).

Looks like a Flux can `publish().refCount(2)`, to ensure that its two consumers will see all elements. However, what if I don't know how many consumers exist or that the number could be dynamic?

Looks like `autoConnect()` or `refCount()` will have late subscribers lose out on the first elements of the source. It's really unclear to me why this could be desirable at all, other than in some niche cases.

If I need to manually `connect()` it seems there's no good way to make it scale for a multi layered application, which will need to collect all `ConnectableFlux`s to connect to throughout multiple layers then `connect()` in an order dependent manner.

Lastly, `cache()` seems to achieve the requirement, but will also cache the whole stream, instead of just guaranteeing that all elements will be delivered to all consumers.

Am I missing something?

Ideally, there should be a simple way to construct the full chain then start it all without losing elements and without using unbounded memory to cache it all.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for `cache`. Can you tell what is the conflict between "cache the whole stream" and "all elements will be delivered", I mean how you can do the second without first?

Comment: Then, you want a cold stream ?  Without code sample it is difficult to understand your problem. It looks like you're trying to apply livestream strategies (hot flux), but you want re-execution behavior (cold stream).

Comment: @IgorArtamonov  The `Ideally` section at the end is what I want.
Looks like having to either settle for `cache()` (potentially unbounded memory use, but easy), or having some facility to collect all `ConnectableFlux`s then call `connect()` on all of them (can become complicated).

Comment: @amanin I really don't care if it will be hot or cold.
I have slightly clarified that I don't want to re-execute the query that generated the source flux. I guess that in Reactor that's called hot flux. What I want is outlined in the `Ideally` section.

Comment: To send elements previously emitted to late subscriber, you either have to still have them in memory (caching the entire flow), or fetch them back from their source.

Comment: @RonVe ah, so you just want to wait until you get all subscriptions ready before starting to publish any events? Maybe you could use just `delaySubscription(Publisher<U> subscriptionDelay)`?

Comment: @amanin sure you need to keep the head in memory, but it is not needed to keep the entire stream.
But, perhaps, with better pipeline setup coordination, you can shrink it to O(1)